# What is the necessary sufficient condition for being projector operators?

Tags: linear-algebra

If an operator $P$ acts on a vector space $V$ and $P^2=P$, then is it correct to say that $P$ is a projector operator onto some subspace $W$ of $V$ ? If not what is the necessary sufficient condition to be a projector operator ?

I know that if an operator is hermitian having eigen values $\{0,1\}$ then surely it is a projector operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P^2 = P$ is necessary and sufficient. Suppose that you let $W = image(P) = \{ P(v) \mid v \in V\}$. Then clearly $P$ maps $V$ *onto* $W$.

Further, suppose that $w \in W$. Then because $P$ is onto $W$, there's a $v$ with $w = P(v)$. And hence $P(w) = P(P(v)) = P^2(v) = P(v) = w$. So $P$ restricted to $W$ is the identity. That makes $P$ clearly a projection onto $W$.

Note: to check that $P$ has eigenvalues $0$ and $1$: every vector in $w$ is an eigenvector with eigenvalue $1$. And for any $v \notin W$, consider $u = v - P(v)$. You have $P(u) = P(v) - P(P(v)) = 0$. This construction gives you a full complement of eigenvectors for eigenvalues $0$ and $1$.

In fact, for any $v$, we have
$$ 
v = P(v) + (v - P(v))
$$
which decomposes $P$ as the sum of an eigenvector for $1$ and an eigenvector for $0$. So the $0$- and 1-eigenspaces clearly span $V$.

Comment: It makes sense thanks alot :)

Answer (score 1):

$P^2=P$ is sufficient condition to be a projection operator...
more precisely $P^2(v)=P(v)$ for every $v\in V$

Answer (score 0):

If V is Hilbert then P is projector if&if P = (P*)P where P* is the adjoint of P. If V is Banach I don't know.